# Change background color of categories in standard mail database

Tags: lotus-notes

As you might know, there's a standard background color set for categories in views of a Lotus notes mail database.
I'm using Notes 8.5.2, so the menu I have in release 9 is not available.

Now I want to know where this is set and if there's any possible way to change that for explicit views.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am not aware there are categories in mail, so I assume you have customized them. Can you post a screenshot of what you want to change?

Comment: Basically I added a new view i made myself in the mail database using categories. What I found out yesterday was, that if I use "Alternating Rows" in this view, it adds a background color automatically for rows, which are categories.

Comment: Please, update question accordingly (screenshot...). And I am in doubts - did alternate rows color solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite clear exactly what you are after, but if you have designer access, check out the help item "Allowing users to set colors in a view".

Basically the view design can include a hidden column that interprets the result of a formula as a foreground &/or background colour for the rest of the row.  It takes a bit of experimenting to get good results.

Comment: In mail databases there's a dark gray background set for categories in views. I want to know where this color is defined and if it's possible to change it.